# C++ Counting Numbers in a String

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a string such as "121", I am trying to count the number of 1's and 2's and then return the string "2112" (because there are 2 one's and 1 two). I am not sure where the problem is in my code but I am getting ridiculous results, if anyone could point out where it goes wrong that would be great. This is my code so far:

It works now, thank you very much.

```
string operate(string s) 
{  
    string input = "121; 
    int count[10] = {0}; 
    string answer; 

    for(int n = 0; n < input.length(); n++) 
    {              
        int a = (input[n]-'0');        
        count[a]++;
    }      

    for(int n = 1; n < 10; n++) 
    { 
        if(count[n] > 0)   
        {  
            stringstream ss;
            ss << count[n] << n;
            answer.append(ss.str());  
        }          
    }         
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose this is a variation of that sequence no one can figure out :p

Comment: Probably is, it is still a legitimate question

Comment: This is not C++, but C# code. There is no "string" variable in C++ - you declare a char* pointer instead.

Comment: @PrahladYeri, Presumably some form of `using std::string;` has appeared before this function. C# has no `stringstream`, and `.length()` would be `.Length`.

Comment: @cjw: A few piece of suggestions: i) Initialize count array to 0.    ii) Don't compare unsigned int with int. Here input.length() returns size_t type which is unsigned int. So make i as unsigned int i for indexing.

Comment: If you want to be more pedantic, it returns `std::string::size_type`, so you can use that for indexing. AFAIK, that's always equivalent to `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three problems here. First, you are not initializing your memory before you use it. It's pretty simple to do so:

```
int count[10]{}; //all 0
```

That failing because of what your compiler supports, something like this will work:

```
int count[10] = {0};
```

Next, you're accessing your array out-of-bounds:

```
int a = input[n];         
count[a]++;
```

First, you assign the numerical value of that character in the string to `a`. If ASCII is in use and the character is `'1'`, that would be 49. Next, you access element `a` of your array. You only have 10 here, but you're probably accessing past that. Since digit character codes are contiguous, just subtract `0` to get the digit value you're looking for in integer form:

```
int a = input[n] - '0';
count[a]++;
```

Taking the example of `'1'`, contiguous means that `'1'` is one past `'0'`, so `'1' - '0'` is 1.

Finally, you're ignoring the first element of the array later on. Make your second loop start indexing from 0, not 1.

---

With that out of the way, may I suggest using a dictionary (with some C++11 for fun)?

```
std::string input = "12113412"; 
std::map<char, int> count; //map characters to counts

for (char c : input) //loop through each character in string
    count[c]++; //this creates the element if it isn't

std::string result;

for (auto p : count) { //each value in map is a pair
   result += std::to_string(p.second) += p.first;
}

std::cout << result;
```

Output:

> 41221314

Comment: Thank you very much, now that it is initialized I am getting normal answers

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple problems with your code.

Firstly, this:

```
int count[10];
```

..won't initialize the values. They will be random memory addresses. You want this:

```
int count[10] = { 0 };
```

..which makes all items in the array initialized to 0.

Also, you only declare 10 items in the array, but this:

```
int a = input[n];
```

..stores "49" in the variable `a` in your example of "121" (1 == 49 ASCII). Then you're doing this:

```
count[49]++; // Wrong.. there is no element 49
```

You appear to be using the array as some sort of `Dictionary`, which is isn't.

Simply changing that to this:

```
int a = input[n] - 48;
count[a]++;
```

..works. This is the full output:

```
std::string operate(std::string s) 
{   
    int count[10] = { 0 }; 
    string answer; 

    for(int n = 0; n < s.length(); n++) 
    {              
        int a = s[n] - 48;
        count[a]++;
    }      

    for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++) 
    { 
        if(count[n] > 0)   
        {  
            stringstream ss;
            ss << count[n] << n;
            answer.append(ss.str());  
        }          
    }         
    return answer;
}
```

..This returns `2112` with the input "121".

Comment: Your dictionary comment brings up a good point. Is it ok if I include a dictionary solution in my answer?

Comment: Never mind, I had an extra line of code that I missed deleting. Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, There, the dictionary seems to be working :) You can tell it was meant for this problem.

Comment: @cjw Look closely. I have removed your `input` variable and used the argument being passed into the function.

Comment: I had an extra cout for checking what input[n] was that I forgot to delete

Comment: @cjw Make sure you upvote and accept answers. Doesn't have to be mine.. but someones. I noticed you haven't done that for any of your questions :)

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation

Comment: I didn't know what that was until now, my bad

Answer (score 1):

The line where you assign to 'a' should be as follows:

```
int a=todigit(input[n]);
```

What you're currently doing is assigning the ASCII value, which will cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: Where is this `todigit` function coming from?

Comment: Yeah, I guess there isn't a standard one, but you could easily do something like: input[n]-'0'

Comment: Actually, I just remembered.  There is the standard 'atoi' function.  In C++, it appears in the "cstdlib" header.

Comment: That takes a C string, not a single character.

Comment: That's true.  I must be tired.  Such a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

int a = input[n]?

input[n] is a char, a will get the ascii code of the corresponding character. For your example, input[0] returns 49 which is the ascii value of char "1". use atoi to convert char to int will do the work.

Comment: `input[0]` doesn't have to return 49. Taking a, perhaps famous, example, it could return 241.

Comment: It returns the numerical value of the first character in the string (I'm still assuming '1' here), which doesn't have a be-all, end-all specific value. It can vary from implementation to implementation. My example of 241 comes from EBCDIC.

Answer (score 0):

You should init count[10].

```
memset(&count, 0, sizeof(count));
```